# HtmlEntities and Zend TextArea

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm fairly new to ZF.

I've been building a website on Zend Framework.
Everything looks good.

But I can't figure out how to resolve 1 problem, that actually is essential when developing article management module.

I've got form that has ZEND_TextArea that looks like this:

```
    $full_text = new Zend_Form_Element_TextArea('full_text');
    $full_text->setLabel('Description:')
            ->setOptions(array('rows' => '28','cols' => '40'))
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
            ->addFilter('HTMLEntities')            
            ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

It work great, it has filter HTMLEntities that is really essential for filtering TextArea.

When displaying the saved data on the website I'm using  `html_entity_decode($item['full_text'])` and it's fine.

But as soon as I try to edit it, it loads encoded text into my textarea, after editing it encodes my already encoded text - and on the front page I get terrible things like:

```
    p;quot;color: #ff0000;&amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;gt;asdasda&amp;amp;amp;lt;/
span&amp;amp;amp;gt;sdas &amp;amp;amp;lt;strong&amp;amp;amp;gt;sdfsdf&amp;amp;amp;
lt;/strong&amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;
```

Maybe someone can help me figure out how to handle this problem, particularly load decoded data into Edit form of TextArea, so that my string doesn't get encoded twice, and when editing it was show in human manner and not into encoded one.

If you can  provide code example - will be really AWESOME!!

thanks!!

Comment: If you're decoding the data before displaying it, why bother encoding it at all?

Comment: I'm decoding it on the website for users, I want to decode it while editing 'cuz encoded data that once again gets encoded after processing in the form. and encoded data is impossible to edit too.

Comment: Don't apply the HtmlEntities filter in the textarea element. Apply HtmlEntities in your model prior to inserting into the database. This filter will apply HtmlEntities to anything that is in the texarea at anytime(even another entity).

Comment: RockyFord that's an option that I have considered, but before getting the data into the edit form I should decode them, so the appear as normal html in the edit form, for that I have to take array, decode the full_text and then put it back into array and display on edit page - how correct is that to do? maybe ZF has another more friendly approach?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use HtmlEntities filter in edit form, if you use it in create form.

Create form :

```
$elements[] = $this->createElement('text','name',array(
    'label'      => 'test',
    'filters'    => array('HtmlEntities'),
));
```

Edit Form :

```
$elements[] = $this->createElement('text','name',array(
    'label'      => 'test',
    'value'      => html_entity_decode($value)
));
```

Your doing html_entity_decode() to set value, to show right 'name' to user..

When UPDATING data in model, you use htmlEntities filter again:

```
$data['name'] = $HtmlEntities->filter($data['name']);
```